# Replacing values in a data.frame according to a value from an other data.frame with the same shape (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to data.frames `df1`and `df2` and with exact the same size and column names, but different values. `df2` has much `NaN` and `df1` only a few. I want every `NaN` in `df2` become `0`, if there is any value in `df1` at the same place (except `NaN`).
E.g.:

```
df1
    a    b   c
0   1    5   NaN
1   2    4   8
2   5    8   5
3   8    8   1
4   7    3   2  
5   NaN  5   1

df2
    a    b   c
0   5    5   NaN
1   NaN  4   8
2   3    8   NaN
3   NaN  NaN 8
4   9    NaN 6  
5   NaN  5   7
```

The result should look like this.

```
df2
    a    b   c
0   5    5   NaN
1   0    4   8
2   3    8   0
3   0    0   8
4   9    0   6  
5   NaN  5   7
```

I am still new to Python and cannot find a solution so far. Unsucsessfully I tried:

```
for row in range(len(df1)):
    if df1.iloc[row,1:] >= 0:
        df2[row,1:] == 0 
    elif df1.iloc[row,1:] == '':
        df2.iloc[row,1:] == ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first set the df2 to 0 where df1 is not null, then take [`np.fmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html) which ignores `NaN` when calculating element wise  max of 2 arrays:

```
np.fmax(df2,df2.mask(df1.notna(),0))
```

EDIT, thanks to @Ben.T for pointing, the above only works with positive values, use the below instead:

```
df2.fillna(0).where(df1.notna())
```

---

```
     a    b    c
0  5.0  5.0  NaN
1  0.0  4.0  8.0
2  3.0  8.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  8.0
4  9.0  0.0  6.0
5  NaN  5.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is select from `df1` where it is `NaN` with `pd.DataFrame.isnull` method and substitute it with `df2` values, as below:

```
>>> df1
   a    b    c
0  0  1.0  3.0
1  1  NaN  2.0
2  2  3.0  4.0
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [1, np.NaN, 3], 'c': [np.NaN, 2, 4]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [1, np.NaN, 3], 'c': [3, 2, 4]})
>>> df1
   a    b    c
0  0  1.0  NaN
1  1  NaN  2.0
2  2  3.0  4.0
>>> df2
   a    b  c
0  0  1.0  3
1  1  NaN  2
2  2  3.0  4
>>> df1[df1.isnull()] = df2
>>> df1
   a    b    c
0  0  1.0  3.0
1  1  NaN  2.0
2  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fill the values in `df2` with `True` or `False` depending when `df1.isna()`. Then, you can replace True and False:

```
df2.fillna(df1.isna()).replace(False,0).replace(True,np.nan)
```

---

```
      a    b    c
0  5.0  5.0  NaN
1  0.0  4.0  8.0
2  3.0  8.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  8.0
4  9.0  0.0  6.0
5  NaN  5.0  7.0
```